# Effective and simpler way to fetch data from xml file

Tags: ios, iphone, xml, cocoa-touch, fetch

I know there are several methods to parse data of an xml file using NSXMLParser, RaptureXML, TouchXML etc. but when I used NSXMLParser methods, it seemed to be a lengthy process as we have to declare strings,arrays and so on. I have an xml file with say around 7 categories and that too with 3 levels, my xml file is of the following [format](http://pastebin.com/FDQzDa5Q), it is copied to supporting files folder of my project. I kindly request to please have a glance at it for understanding.

I have around 21 tags and I need to fetch data from each category which means I need to declare around 21 arrays, separate strings etc. if at all I am not wrong!

I tried to fetch the data from one category,animal level one. But I observe no data in array, I don't know how to move on from here:

```
-(void)parseAndFetchWords
{
    self.animalsWordsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSString *xmlFilePath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"strings" ofType:@"xml"];
    NSURL *xmlLocationURL = [NSURL URLWithString:xmlFilePath];
    self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlLocationURL];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];
}
#pragma mark - Parser Delegate
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentElement = nil;
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"animalLevelOne"])
    {
        self.animalName = [NSMutableString string];
        self.animalHint = [NSMutableString string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet]];

    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"animalLevelOne"])
    {
        [animalName appendString:string];
    }
    else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"animalLevelOne"])
    {
        [animalHint appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"animalLevelOne"])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dictionary setObject:animalName forKey:@"animalName"];
        [dictionary setObject:animalHint forKey:@"animalHint"];
        //And finally
        [self.animalsWordsArray addObject:dictionary];
    }
}
```

Can some one please suggest a better and simple way to fetch data from xml, may be without parsing, like converting xml to plist file or dictionary etc. through which code optimisation can also be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a cool solution on how to parse an xml file without any hassle.

Take a model class and name it as XMLParser with header and main files,declare all the necessary variables and a method in model class,say in my case it is:

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableString *currentElementValue;
@property(strong,nonatomic) wordJumblesAppDelegate *appDelegate;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *objects;

//Method for parsing....
-(XMLParser *)initXMLParser;
```

Please do understand the currentElementValue is the value in each tag of whole xml file and appDelegate object is declared to store all the parsed data in dictionary declared in delegate class.Objects are nothing but an array for storing all the values of each tag.

Let's now move on with the implementation part

```
-(XMLParser *)initXMLParser
{
    self = [super init];
    self.appDelegate = (gameAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    return self;
}
```

Implement the parser delegate methods:

```
//Start parsing the xml file using did start element
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDictionary
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"resources"])
    {
        appDelegate.categoryWords = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"string-array"])
    {
        self.objects = [NSMutableArray array];
        if (objects)
        {
            [appDelegate.categoryWords setObject:objects forKey:[attributeDictionary objectForKey:@"name"]];
        }
    }
}

//Search for characters in each tag and assign the value to our currentElementValue
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if(!currentElementValue)
    {
        self.currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    }
    else
    {
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];
    }
}

//Finally add the currentElementValue to our objects array
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"resources"])
        return;
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"string-array"])
    {
    }
    else
    {
        [objects  addObject:currentElementValue];
    }
    self.currentElementValue = nil;
}
```

Please do observe that we are storing the objects array in category words dictionary declared in application delegate file so that we can use the dictionary to access all the values of xml file where ever required in our project.

Finally do the necessary parsing during application launch in did finish launching method,i.e.:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSString *xmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"categoryWords" ofType:@"xml"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:xmlFilePath];

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    //Initialize the delegate.
    XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

    //Set delegate
    [xmlParser setDelegate:(id)parser];

    //Start parsing the XML file.
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

    if(success)
);
    else
        NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
return YES;
}
```

**Sample Code to retrieve the data from categoryWords dictionary**

```
NSArray *allCategories = [applicationDelegate.categoryWords allKeys];
for (NSString *category in allCategories)
{
   if ([category isEqualToString:@"animalLevelOne"])
   {
      NSArray *animalsEasyData = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[applicationDelegate.categoryWords objectForKey:category]];
      for (NSArray *animalsEasy in animalsEasyData)
      {
         for (NSString *animal in animalsEasy)
         {
            NSArray *trimmedAnimalsEasyData = [animal componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
            [self.animalsEasyWords addObject:[trimmedAnimalsEasyData objectAtIndex:0]];
            [self.animalsEasyHints addObject:[trimmedAnimalsEasyData objectAtIndex:1]];
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps someone,thanks,happy coding :)

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code to store doctionary in `.plist`

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *docFilePath = [documentsDirstringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserSettings.plist"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

// add the data to dict here
[dict setObject:allMsgs forKey:@"allMsgsKey"];

// save the data as plist`enter code here`
[dict writeToFile:docFilePath atomically:YES];
[dict release];
```

Comment: Sorry,I guess you didn't go through my question properly,my concern was not regarding storing dictionary in plist,it is fetching data from xml file :)